# Using Multiple Classes for a Clock in Bluej

Tags: java, bluej

(**Before I begin sorry for the large unorganized code, I'm still relatively new**)

I'm currently using BlueJ for a project of mine, and I need a timer to actually time each level of the game. I'm using the Try and Catch commands to actually have timer, and I'm trying to use two different classes, I was wondering if there is a better way to do this, or how would I go about referencing the two inside of each other. Thanks!

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class grid5x5{

String a= "x";
String b= "x";
String c= "x";
String d= "x";
String e= "x";
String f= "x";
String g= "x";
String h= "x";
String i= "x";
String j= "x";
String k= "x";
String l= "x";
String m= "x";
String n= "x";
String o= "x";
String p= "x";
String q= "x";
String r= "x";
String s= "x";
String t= "x";
String u= "x";
String v= "x";
String w= "x";
String x= "x";
String y= "x";
private int a1;
private int a2;
private int a3;
public int a4=2;
public void Grid(){
    while(a4==2){
    System.out.println('\f');
    Random rand = new Random();
    int z = rand.nextInt(25) + 1;

    if (z==1){
         a= "O";
           a1=11;
    }
    if (z==2){
         b= "O";
           a1=21;
    }
    if (z==3){
         c= "O";
           a1=31;
    }
    if (z==4){
         d= "O";
           a1=41;
    }
    if (z==5){
         e= "O";
           a1=51;
    }
    if (z==6){
         f= "O";
           a1=12;
    }
    if (z==7){
         g= "O";
           a1=22;
    }
    if (z==8){
         h= "O";
           a1=32;
    }
    if (z==9){
         i= "O";
           a1=42;
    }
    if (z==10){
         j= "O";
           a1=52;
    }
    if (z==11){
         k= "O";
           a1=13;
    }
    if (z==12){
         l= "O";
           a1=23;
    }
    if (z==13){
         m= "O";
           a1=33;
    }
    if (z==14){
         n= "O";
           a1=43;
    }
    if (z==15){
         o= "O";
           a1=53;
    }
    if (z==16){
         p= "O";
           a1=14;
        }
    if (z==17){
         q= "O";
           a1=24;
    }
    if (z==18){
         r= "O";
           a1=34;
    }
    if (z==19){
         s= "O";
           a1=44;
    }
    if (z==20){
         t= "O";
           a1=54;
    }
    if (z==21){
         u= "O";
           a1=15;
    }
    if (z==22){
         v= "O";
           a1=25;
    }
    if (z==23){
         w= "O";
           a1=35;
    }
    if (z==24){
         x= "O";
           a1=45;
    }
    if (z==25){
         y= "O";
           a1=55;
    }
    else{

    }
    System.out.println("  1 2 3 4 5");
    System.out.println("1 "+a+" "+b+" "+c+" "+d+" "+e);
    System.out.println("2 "+f+" "+g+" "+h+" "+i+" "+j);
    System.out.println("3 "+k+" "+l+" "+m+" "+n+" "+o);
    System.out.println("4 "+p+" "+q+" "+r+" "+s+" "+t); 
    System.out.println("5 "+u+" "+v+" "+w+" "+x+" "+y);
    System.out.println("Points: "+a2);
    System.out.println("Time: "+a3);
    int inVar;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the Coordinates: ");
    inVar = input.nextInt();
    if(inVar==a1){
        System.out.println('\f');
        System.out.println("CORRECT!");
        a2=a2+1;
    }
    else{
        a4=a4+1;
    }

     a= "x";
     b= "x";
     c= "x";
     d= "x";
     e= "x";
     f= "x";
     g= "x";
     h= "x";
     i= "x";
     j= "x";
     k= "x";
     l= "x";
     m= "x";
     n= "x";
     o= "x";
     p= "x";
     q= "x";
     r= "x";
     s= "x";
     t= "x";
     u= "x";
     v= "x";
     w= "x";
     x= "x";
     y= "x";
     System.out.println('\f');

    }

    System.out.println('\f');
    System.out.println("INCORRECT, Game Over");
    System.out.println("Total Points: "+a2);
    System.out.println("Thanks for playing!");
}
}
```

Here is my other block of code for the other class

```
public class Timer
{
public int a5=5000;

public void timer(){
    while(a4==2) {
     try {Thread.sleep(1000);}
     catch (InterruptedException ie){}
     a5=a5-100;
     if(a5<300){
         a5=300;
        }
     else
     {
     }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: see java.util.Timer and javax.swing.Timer

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is fix these varible names.  I can't easily understand what this code is supposed to do because of this issue.  I seggusts you read [this guide on varible names](https://dzone.com/articles/best-practices-variable-and).

Also, typically in Java class names start with uppercase letters and method names start with lowercase letters, but this isn't a huge problem.

As for using your timer, you will create a new instance of the object in the same place you declare your other variables:

```
Time timer = new Timer();
```

To call the method inside of timer, you will use the timer varible that contains an instance of the Timer class to call the method:

```
timer.timer();
```

Another issue I see with this code is that you are attempting to use varible from your main class in the timer class.  I seggusts you add a constructor to the timer class that accepts an instance of your main class so you can access the variables from the timer class (this breaks encapsulation, but that isn't a serious problem right now).

Finally, there is a serious logic problem  with this code.  Right now, calling the timer method will hang the program as you are calling Thread.sleep on the main thread.  You need to run the program on a diffrent thread than the timer.  I seggust that you allow the Timer class to implement Runnable, name the time method run, and start the timer with:

```
new Thread(new Timer(this)).run();
```

Comment: Yeah, that logic problem I was trying to solve using multiple classes. Could you possible explain a little more what 'this' is?

Comment: 'this' is referring to the current instance of the class in the running method.  The class itself can't store data in the variables (unless they're static), so when you use 'this' you're referring to the object with the variables that the method is in right now.  [This OO tutorial](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J3a_OOPBasics.html) might help you understand how instances work somewhat better, as it is one of the crucial concepts you must understand to be a good Java programmer.